# In sublime text 4, how to hide embeded code's symbols in the `go to symbol` panel when in a markdown file?

Tags: sublimetext4

In sublime text 4, now `go to symbol` will show mixed symbols. For example. if I have a markdown file, and inside the file there is some go snippet code, go to symbol will show both markdown source’s symbol and go source’s symbol mixed, and the mixed mess make `go to symbol` help less to show the markdown’s structure.

So is there a way to restrict the `go to symbol` only show symbol from the main source? like inside a `*.md` file, only show markdown’s symbol? Like the old days?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-restrict-go-to-symbol-only-show-symbol-from-one-source/64066

There is a patch to do this: https://github.com/deathaxe/sublime-packages/blob/838d21fe511b993ccaff86daa7dac663b58ecf91/Markdown/Symbol%20List%20-%20Hide.tmPreferences

But it's not released yet. You can manually create a `Symbol List - Hide.tmPreferences` file under sublime text's `Pacakges/Markdown/` folder with the content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>
        text.html.markdown markup.raw.code-fence,
        text.html.markdown meta.toc-list.id
    </string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>showInSymbolList</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>showInIndexedSymbolList</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To do this, you may need install `PacakgeSourceViewer` package, and extract the `Markdown` package first.